# Are controller nodes always null inside setOnCloseRequest?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I have the following code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            ...

            primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(button)
                }

            });

            ...
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println(button);
    }

}
```

I run it, then click on the close button, and this is the output:

```
Button[id=button, styleClass=button]'button'
null
```

Why is button null when called inside setOnCloseRequest?

Comment: `@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized in the controller. `start(..)` is not called on the controller, so `button` is null on the instance on which `start(...)` is called.

Comment: That's right!  I've managed to solve the problem by using the proper instance. Thanks a lot, @James_D!